# Insertion of html5 number input value into db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to insert value of html 5 input control into db.But its value is inserting as null.Here is my code.
View:

```
  @Html.LabelFor( m => m.noOfCars)
 <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" step="1">
```

Model:

```
   public string noOfCars { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
        [httpPost]
        public ActionResult AddVehicles(AddSpaces adspace)
         {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
           string userName = User.Identity.Name;
           var queryUser = from user in Session.Query<AddSpaces>()
                           where user.email == userName
                           select user;

           if (queryUser.Count() > 0)
           {
               foreach (var updateSpaces in queryUser)
               {
                    updateSpaces.BPH = adspace.noOfCars;
               }
                  Session.SaveChanges();
           }
        }
     }
```

I have changed my model's noOfCars property to int but it does not works.

Comment: Seems like you're missing the model as parameter. What is `adspace`?

Comment: sorry,mistakenly i posted wrong code.Now i updated it.That is not working

Comment: Is the model (`adspac`) null or just `noOfCars`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your input field in order for MVC to bind it for you.

```
 @Html.LabelFor( m => m.noOfCars)
 <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" step="1" name="noOfCars">
```

alternatively you can use the HTML helper to help you name things. this should work

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.noOfCars, new { type = "number", min = "1", max = "1000" })
```

The first parameter works the same as the LabelFor, and the second parameter is an annonymous method that contains the key value pairs that will be output as attributes to your HTML element.